# Is 「出ちゃいけません」 short for 「出ちゃってはいけません」?

Tags: grammar, verbs, casual

The sentence in question:

> 道の外側に出ちゃいけません！

While it is obvious what it means, I am wondering how precisely it is constructed grammatically.

The textbook way of expressing "must not do" using いけない is:

[て-Form] は いけない

So going by that I would construct it as follows:

出る　→　出ちゃう　→　出ちゃって　→　出ちゃってはいけません

So I assume 「出ちゃいけません」 is simply a shortened form of this grammar.

Is that correct?

If yes, is this common?

If no, how is 「出ちゃいけません」 made up grammatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, short for 出ちゃってはいけません would be 出ちゃっちゃいけません. ～ては itself contracts to ～ちゃ (compare ではない and じゃない), so 出ちゃいけません is a contracted form of 出てはいけません. This kind of contraction is extremely common.

Comment: Oh, right, makes sense. I completely forgot about ては→ちゃ.